# how to change css when ng-select is used?

Tags: css, angular

I am currently using ng-select for drop down like

```
<ng-select [items]="tests"
           (data)="signalChanged($event)"
           [active]="test"
           id="test)">
</ng-select>
```

I want to change the back ground color of the active element in the drop down list. How do I access it's css?

Comment: The link says file not found.

Answer (score 11):

You can customize as per official documentation. To find exact class you need to override, do inspect and identify the class.

```
<ng-select class="custom"></ng-select>
.ng-select.custom {
    border:0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.ng-select.custom .ng-select-container  {            
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

If you are using ViewEncapsulation, your should use special ::ng-deep selector which will prevent scoping for nested selectors.

```
.ng-select.custom ::ng-deep .ng-select-container  {            
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select#custom-styles has more details  around the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you override the styles as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#custom-styles). In addition to that try setting the *Encapsulation* for the component.

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from ng-select [Documentation page](https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select/#/examples/highlight-color)

> The backgrond color and text color of the highlighted option in the
>   drop-down can be changed using the highlightColor and
>   highlightTextColor properties, as shown in the following example.
>   Single select
>
> Component template
>
> ```
> <ng-select
>     highlightColor="#9575cd"
>     highlightTextColor="#fff"
>     [options]="characters">
> </ng-select>
> ```
>
> Multiple select
>
> Component template
>
> ```
> <ng-select
>     highlightColor="#9575cd"
>     highlightTextColor="#fff"
>     [options]="characters"
>     [multiple]="true">
> </ng-select>
> ```

Comment: highlightColor="#9575cd"
    highlightTextColor="#fff" Options are not working for ng-select.

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Comment: @JamesPoulose, fixed :)